# XPath to find anchor with specific domain in this HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="profile-bio-full">
  <p>Bla bla bla bla </p>
  <p>Site: <a href="http://www.something.com" rel="nofollow">something.com</a></p>
  <p>Facebook: <a href="http://www.facebook.com" rel="nofollow">facebook.com</a></p>
  <p>Twitter: <a href="http://www.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">www.twitter.com</a></p>
</div>
```

And i need to get the Twitter URL (the href "a" property).

I'm using Rails with Nokogiri gem, and using Nokogiri xPath funciton.

I'm using this xPath

```
//div[contains(@id, "profile-bio-full")]/a[contains(@href, "twitter.com")]
```

But don't work :( . Any guesses?

Comment: "don't work" should be an immediate red flag that tells you to specify (a) what you wanted to happen, and (b) what actually happened. In other words, what is the empirical data that leads you to believe it didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your single forward slash before your `a` matcher specifies that the `a` element needs to be an immediate child of `div` -- but it's not, it's a child of `p`.

You can either do this:

```
//div[contains(@id, "profile-bio-full")]/p/a[contains(@href, "twitter.com")]
```

Or you can just change `/a` to `//a` to mean the `a` just has to be a descendant rather than an immediate child.

```
//div[contains(@id, "profile-bio-full")]//a[contains(@href, "twitter.com")]
```

Comment: Note that if you know the `id` exactly, you can make this a hair simpler and faster with the XPath: `//div[@id="profile-bio-full"]//a[contains(@href,"twitter.com")]`

Comment: @Phrogz: +1 I agree: an identifier should be an exact match.